# JQuery пауза бесконечного цикла при наведении курсора

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите как реализовать? Нужно как-то повесить hover на список и делать паузу/продолжение. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/killbond/p4JU7/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И в чем сложность ?

http://jsfiddle.net/p4JU7/7/

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    animaze();
    var hovered = 0,
        current;

    function animaze() {
        current = $('ul li').eq(0).animate({
            marginLeft: -106
        }, 2500, 'linear', function () {
            $('ul li').eq(0).appendTo($('ul'));
            $('ul li').last().css({
                marginLeft: 0
            });
            if (!hovered) animaze();
        });
    }
    $('ul').hover(

    function () {
        current.stop();
        hovered = 1;
    },

    function () {

        hovered = 0;
        animaze();
    }

    );
});
```

вот с [Pause plugin](http://tobia.github.io/Pause/)

http://jsfiddle.net/p4JU7/8/

Comment: Прошу прощения, но там с разметкой вроде ошибка, тк <li> не может обрамлять ничего кроме <ul>?

    <ul>
        <div>
            <li><div>1</div></li>
            <li><div>2</div></li>
            <li><div>3</div></li>
            <li><div>4</div></li>
            <li><div>5</div></li>
            <li><div>6</div></li>
        </div>
    </ul>

Comment: ага, есть такое, я на разметку не смотрел. только не только ul а еще и 

>> `<ul>, <ol> or <menu>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: множественный ховер немного тормозит слайдер

Comment: код некорректный, не спорю, суть не в разметке

Comment: @NoName не понял, где там множественный ховер. там торможение из-за того что в результате остановки элементу двигаться недалеко, а если сделать finish(). то дергается, есть ещё вот такой момент: http://tobia.github.io/Pause/

Comment: После каждого последующего наведения курсора замедляет движение примерно в 2 раза. Как это исправить?

Comment: это когда много раз проводишь мышкой, якобы случайно)

Comment: Ок, а тут как быть? нужно задержку вводить или с queue играться, как, например, здесь?

http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: finish() можно сделать если по простому, либо stop() вообще не делать и позволять спрайту доезжать до своего места. либо воспользоваться плагином pause/resume